# Error when collecting multiple resultset from stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure which I have written. I am trying to collecting multiple result set from it. But unfortunately I am getting an error

> A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll.

The message is the error I keep seeing.

I have tried all I can but don't know were the error is, I have tested my stored procedure it works fine.

Stored procedure:

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Collectcompanyservicewithpackages]
     @CompanyID int     
 AS
     select * 
     from Serviceduration 
     where Client_CompanyID = @CompanyID;

     select Serviceitem.* 
     from Serviceduration, Serviceitem
     where Client_CompanyID = @CompanyID 
       and Serviceduration.ServicedurationID = Serviceitem.ServicedurationID;

     select ServiceitemPackage.* 
     from Serviceduration, Serviceitem, ServiceitemPackage
     where Client_CompanyID = @CompanyID 
       and Serviceduration.ServicedurationID = Serviceitem.ServicedurationID 
       and Serviceitem.ServiceitemID = ServiceitemPackage.ServiceitemID
```

Database modules:

Snippet

```
public List<Serviceview> GetFirmServiceswithpackages_sp(int CompanyID)
{
        List<Serviceview> allservices = null;

        IEnumerable<Serviceduration> servicedurations = null;

        IEnumerable<Serviceitem> serviceitems = null;

        IEnumerable<ServiceitemPackage> serviceitempackages = null;

        using(context){

            Debug.WriteLine("App got here for starters .........................");


            // If using Code First we need to make sure the model is built before we open the connection 
            // This isn't required for models created with the EF Designer 
            //context.Database.Initialize(force: false); 

            // Create a SQL command to execute the sproc
            var cmd = context.Database.Connection.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "Collectcompanyservicewithpackages  @CompanyID";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            DbParameter inputparameter = new SqlParameter();
           inputparameter.DbType = DbType.Int64;
           inputparameter.ParameterName = "CompanyID";
           inputparameter.Value = CompanyID;
           inputparameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

           cmd.Parameters.Add(inputparameter);

            try
            {
                // Run the sproc
                context.Database.Connection.Open();
                var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                // Read Blogs from the first result set
                var durations = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context)
                    .ObjectContext
                    .Translate<Serviceduration>(reader, "Servicedurations", MergeOption.AppendOnly);  

                servicedurations = this.Extractdurations(durations);

                Debug.WriteLine("No of duration "+servicedurations.Count());

                // Move to second result set and read Serviceitems in cart 
                reader.NextResult();

                var services4sale = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context)
                    .ObjectContext
                    .Translate<Serviceitem>(reader, "Serviceitems", MergeOption.AppendOnly);

                serviceitems = this.Extractservices(services4sale);

                Debug.WriteLine("No of services  "+serviceitems.Count() );

                // Move to second result set and read Serviceitems in cart 
                reader.NextResult();

                var packages = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context)
                    .ObjectContext
                    .Translate<ServiceitemPackage>(reader, "ServiceitemPackages", MergeOption.AppendOnly);

                serviceitempackages = this.Extractpackages(packages);

                Debug.WriteLine("No of packages ...."+ serviceitempackages.Count()); 

                allservices = this.ReturnServiceincart(servicedurations, serviceitems, serviceitempackages);

            }
            catch(SqlException e){

                Debug.WriteLine("Cause of the error "+e.InnerException.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                context.Database.Connection.Close();
            }
        }

        return allservices;
    }
```

//The methods below are used to extract Enumerables from the Object Resultset. I would love to call them helper methods

```
   //This is the help method that would help us to do the final crafting of our stored procedure run around
    private List<Serviceview> ReturnServiceincart(IEnumerable<Serviceduration> durations, IEnumerable<Serviceitem> services, IEnumerable<ServiceitemPackage> packages)
    {
        List<Serviceview> allservices = new List<Serviceview>();

        if(services != null){

            foreach(var service in services){

                Serviceview view = new Serviceview()
                {
                    Name = service.Name,
                    Cost = service.Cost,
                    Description = service.Description,
                    Durationname = durations.Where(item=>item.ServicedurationID == service.ServicedurationID).Select(item=>item.Duration).SingleOrDefault<string>(),
                    IsVisible = service.IsVisible,
                    Packages = Returnpackages(service.ServiceitemID, packages)  //Note we are not passing service.ServiceitemPackage, cos we are avoiding a lazy loading cos it already been returned in stored procedure.
                };
            }
        }

        return allservices;
    }

    private IEnumerable<Serviceduration> Extractdurations(ObjectResult<Serviceduration> durations)
    {
        IEnumerable<Serviceduration> servicedurations = durations.AsEnumerable<Serviceduration>();

        return servicedurations;
    }

    private IEnumerable<Serviceitem> Extractservices(ObjectResult<Serviceitem> services4sale)
    {
        IEnumerable<Serviceitem> serviceitems = services4sale.AsEnumerable<Serviceitem>();

        return serviceitems;
    }

    private IEnumerable<ServiceitemPackage> Extractpackages(ObjectResult<ServiceitemPackage> packages)
    {
        IEnumerable<ServiceitemPackage> servicepackages = packages.AsEnumerable<ServiceitemPackage>();

        return servicepackages;
    }

    //Because the packages here would contain all packages for all company services we need to filter with a service ID
    private List<string> Returnpackages(int ServiceitemID, IEnumerable<ServiceitemPackage> packageitems)
    {
        List<string> packages = new List<string>();

        foreach(var package in packageitems){
            if(package.ServiceitemID == ServiceitemID)
               packages.Add(package.PackageName);
        }

        return packages;
    }
```

Changes made below
  **cmd.CommandText = "Collectcompanyservicewithpackages";**

After making  a change to the query. I get the error message

The result of the query can not be enumerable more than once.

The new error is on the line

**allservices = this.ReturnServiceincart(servicedurations, serviceitems, serviceitempackages);**

Comment: Could you please format the code a little better, provide the exception details, and provide the rest of the Ado.Net code ?

Comment: Have you tried "cmd.CommandText = "Collectcompanyservicewithpackages"; OR cmd.CommandText = "Collectcompanyservicewithpackages  @CompanyID = @CompanyID";

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Thanks @marc. Would change it later. But any head on what could cause the error. Even though that style is old, I tried it and it works. So the problem is the code not the sql

Comment: Woow  @Anthony Horne. I tried the first option and I am making head way. Sql Error is gone but new errror is. The result of a query cannot be enumerated more than once.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: The result of a query cannot be enumerated more than once.

Error is referring to

Answer (score 0):

cmd.CommandText = "Collectcompanyservicewithpackages";

This line solved the magic.

After this I closed the command and the reader object.

It works fine now.